# update query not working c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have used this query in sql management studio and it works, I have tried a shortened query without the `and` condition and it works, why is the `and` condition breaking the code?

```
string dbQuery = "update log_file set updated = @true where urn = @urn and companyid = @companyid";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@urn", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = urn;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@companyid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = companyid;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@true", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = 0;

cmd.CommandText = (dbQuery);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What database you using?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: What do you mean by it worked without the `AND`? How do you see that the `AND` breaking your code?

Comment: update log_file set updated = 0  << shortened without and condition

Comment: Is your connection disposed (closed) properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with false for Bit type

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@true", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = false;
```

If you want use 0 as value, replace type parameter with Int

Comment: that would mean the shortened query wouldnt work but it does, plus i tried changing types to int and bit, and changing types in sql server and it still does not work

Comment: @Candie: Have you got a reference for not being able to use 0? I had a brief look (because it surprised me) and couldn't find anything stating that... Given 1/0 works in SQL I'd be surprised if the .NET drivers didn't allow it...

Answer (score 2):

If `and companyid = @companyid` is causing it not to work (and I assume you mean the update didn't happen rather than getting an error message then the only explanation is that the companyid that you are passing isn't correct. Likely your tests in Management Studio are using the values you think it should have rather than the ones it actually does.

You should confirm that all the parameters are correct in a debug session and then work out why not if they aren't.

Comment: i have tested values and they are correct, i am passing them in manualy as it is a web service so i know values are correct

Comment: using this method i test the values System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sqlparameter["@urn"].value); gives me the values, i have even tried hard coding it.

Comment: Could you perhaps explicitly show the query that is working and the one that isn't? And are you saying that sending a hardcoded sql statement with no parameterisation at all still fails whereas it works in Management studio? If so then the only thing I can think of is that you are connecting to the wrong server or you are using transactions somewhere and not correctly committing it...

Comment: ok in sql this works: update log_file set updated = 1 where urn = 115 and companyid = 1  , i pass same values into my query and it does not

Comment: Is your command object freshly created (wondering if it might be contaminated with a previous query)?

Comment: ok my fault i mixed the values of urn and companyid when calling the method. oops

Comment: Glad you've got to the bottom. This is why I always say to check values at the point they are used as the first thing you do when a call is not doing what you expect.